# elastic search - Java api client range query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, range, date-range

I am migrating a java application from elastic search high level client to java api client.
There is a range query like this in the code.
`QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("startDate").lte(dateUtils.today())`
Need to change this to java api client code.
Could someone help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/searching.html

```
Query dateRangeQuery = RangeQuery.of(r -> r
    .field("startDate")
    .lte(dateUtils.today()) 
)._toQuery();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to create a similar query using Query.of()

```
Query dateRangeQuery = Query.of(q -> q
    .range(r -> r
        .field("field")
        .lte(dateUtils.today()) 
    )
);
```